# Sidekiq testnig in rspec gave wrong argument error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rubygems, sidekiq

when i try to test the rspec for the sidekiq, it sending the params as string to the method.

for example:

my rspec

" `expect(User::RemoveAccess).to have_enqueued_sidekiq_job(user.id,user_account_ids)`
"

here user account ids is an array
like user_account_ids = user.pluck(:account_ids)

my ruby code:

```
  User::RemoveAccess.perform_async(user.id,user.pluck(:account_ids))
```

the error I'm getting in rspec is:

```
expected to have an enqueued User::RemoveAccess job
         arguments: [12670, ["e012-40d-4f50-8d96-14"]]
       found
         arguments: [[12670, "e012-40d-4f50-8d96-14"]]
```

I'm not sure where I'm getting wrong, is any thing i missed?.

Comment: These might help you [issue1](https://github.com/philostler/rspec-sidekiq/issues/162), [issue2](https://github.com/philostler/rspec-sidekiq/issues/168), [issue3](https://github.com/philostler/rspec-sidekiq/issues/133)

Answer (score 0):

The wrong arguments error is happening because you are calling .pluck on a single user instance and not an active record collection

If you want an array, you need to change this

```
user.pluck(:account_ids)
```

To this

```
users.pluck(:account_ids)
```